# Not Solving:RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to calculate the General Provident Funds, but there is some malfunctioning with my code, can anyone help me out, please.

```
amt=int(input("Enter Current total in GPF fund\n"))
dud=int(input("Enter Amount Duduction per month for Fund\n"))
d=dud
n=int(input("Enter No. of years you want to calculate\n"))
def cal_cirint(amt,dud):
    amt=amt+(dud*12)
    amt=amt+(amt*0.08)
    am=amt
    if n==1:
        return amt
    if n>1:
      for i in range (2,n):
        a=cal_cirint(am,d)
      return amt
    if n==0:
        return False
print(cal_cirint(amt,dud))
```

Comment: "there is some malfunctioning" what is the problem ? Can you share the error trace ?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not terminating condition for your recursive function. You need to pass the years as a parameter to the function and replace all those `if n` conditions with the variable years.

so something like this

```
amt=int(input("Enter Current total in GPF fund\n"))
dud=int(input("Enter Amount Duduction per month for Fund\n"))
d=dud
n=int(input("Enter No. of years you want to calculate\n"))
def cal_cirint(amt,dud,year):
    print(f"amt: {amt} dud: {dud} year: {year}")
    amt=amt+(dud*12)
    amt=amt+(amt*0.08)
    if year==1:
        return amt

    if year>1:
        amt += cal_cirint(amt,dud,year-1)
        return amt
    if year==0:
        return 0

print(cal_cirint(amt,dud,n))
```

And the result looks like as

```
Enter Current total in GPF fund
100
Enter Amount Duduction per month for Fund
10
Enter No. of years you want to calculate
3
amt: 100 dud: 10 year: 3
amt: 237.6 dud: 10 year: 2
amt: 386.208 dud: 10 year: 1
1170.51264
```

I hope you understood the logic. There needs to be a terminating condition, otherwise the recursive function will run for over until stack overflows.

Comment: If add every "if" condition for each year then this code is not easy. I have to make it static for every single year.

Comment: What I meant was replace n with a variable y in your code